# how many ways is there to factor matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

There is one way which is the $A = LU$ composition form.  I know this is not unique way because take two matrices and multiply and you can get $A$.  For a number like $72$ it is factorizable into $8*9$ but also $36*2$ or $12*6$.  Is there similarly a finite number of different way to factor matrix $A$?  Or is there infinitely many ways?

Comment: A remark, taking different solutions to $A_iA_j=I$, one gets that $(LA_i)(A_jU)=A$.

Comment: But $A$ is particular matrix.  Then the first equation is only unique.  $A_i$ and $A_j = A_i^{-1}$.  How can get different solutions?

Comment: Let $A = I$ (identity matrix) and let $\lambda \ne 0$. Then $L = \lambda I$ is lower triangular, $U = \lambda^{-1}I $ is upper triangular, and $A = LU$. Infinitely many different solutions. You have to require additional properties to remove this non-uniqueness, e.g. require that all diagonal elements of $L$ are either 0 or 1.

Comment: I mean that if $LU=A$ then we have $A=(LA_i)(A_i^{-1}U)$ for many different $A_i$.

Comment: yes, of course!

Comment: @Olivier Oloa: But is $LA_i$ lower triangular?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Oh I did not understand it was in the form lower matrix  $\cdot$ upper matrix, this is not clear to me in the OP question ;)

Comment: No in my question the composition can be any.  I agree with Oliver's answer.

Comment: Related question here for how many ways to factor a number. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402611/combinatorics-how-many-ways-to-combine-prime-factors)