# combinatorics - how many ways to combine prime factors

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Given a number written as prime factors, `12 = 2 * 2 * 3,`

```
12 = 3 * 4  (considered same as 12 = 4 * 3)
12 = 2 * 6
12 = 2 * 2 * 3
12 = 12
```

So there are `4` ways to combine prime factors.

Now given a number `N = a1^p1 * a2^p2 * ... * an^pn`

How many ways to combine the prime factors?

Comment: Hm, smells a bit related to the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups (but may be a bit too advanced for you).

Comment: @Sean Is that something within the scope of basic abstract algebra?

Comment: Possibly related: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201690/computing-the-number-of-nonisomorphic-finite-abelian-groups-of-order-n) shows how to compute the number of ways if you do not allow multiplication of different primes (so $12=2\cdot 2 \cdot 3$ and $12 = 4 \cdot 3$ are counted, but it does not count $12 =2 \cdot 6$ or $12 = 12$).

Comment: @WeishiZeng Yes, it's a theorem that describes isomorphisms between finite abelian groups.

Comment: @Joffan edited to include 12 = 12

Comment: When $N=a_1^{p_1}$, there is $P(p_1)$ different ways where $P(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$. I don't think there is a closed form answer for this question because we don't know even a closed form for the number of partitions.

Comment: @Merdanov I think you are right. I looked it up in Wiki. It seems we only have approximation formulas and recurrence relations for P(n). But at least I found an official problem definition that this question most relates to. Thanks. btw, how did you print the formulas nicely in comments?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference same way as in answering by just putting "$" signs and using appropriate latex text between those signs.

Comment: This problem has been studied under the name "partitions of a multiset". Knuth gives an algorithm for generating all the partitions in section 7.2.1.5 of "The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4" but no formula for the number.

Comment: This is  OEIS A001055. https://oeis.org/A001055

Comment: @awkward link for ref to the book (http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc3b.pdf) page 25. The algorithm mentioned in the book only generate partitions for {1,...,n}. which are different, as this question contains duplicates. (e.g. 2,2*,3 | 3* and 2,2*,3* | 3 should considered same.) I couldn't find a way to skip duplicates on the fly. (I have to remove duplicates after they are generated.)

Comment: @weishizeng In the pre-fasicle you linked to, it's "Algorithm M (Multipartitions in decreasing lexicographic order)" on page 39.